# Display huge columns in a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to show more than 500 columns in a grid with a scroll bar?
Or Is there any other way?

Comment: Honestly - i would think about usability with 500 columns. If as a user I was faced with 500 columns I would go elsewhere. And if it was my job to use a system with 500 columns I would probably resign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but highly unusable.  You need to revisit your requirments I think and decide on what it is the user actually needs.  I could think of very few occasions where this would be an appropriate UI.